# how do I know if a fan page has been deleted?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to know if a fan page has been deleted from facebook.

If I ask the page's info through the page ID :
* http://graph.facebook.com/280605915313044 -> the page exists and i get the json response
* http://graph.facebook.com/129839953774767 -> the page has been deleted (by me) and the response is "false"

The same response (false) is given from facebook in others cases for example when the page has some restriction (age restriction, alchool restriction...)

I would like to know if there's a specific parameter returning the deletion info.

thank you

Comment: Please use english in your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to determine why you can't see a page, just that you can't.
Very few pages get deleted though, it's more likely there's a restriction in place or the page was merged with another page (in which case the exception will give you the new page ID)